# Firebase arrayRemove takes very long time in modular version

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm refactoring my firebase code to support the modular firebase version.

After I refactored the "arrayRemove" function, I noticed that it started to take a very long time to execute. Something about 1 minute. At v8, that was about 1 seconds

Here is my code:

```
  const userRef = doc(db, 'users', userId)
  try {
    await updateDoc(userRef, {
      items: arrayRemove(itemId),
    })

    console.log('REMOVED')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

Execution of this code takes around one minute. The same action with the same data in the same environment for the older version takes about one second. The rest functions works fast.

Firebase version: 9.6.1

Any ideas why it takes so long and how to make it faster?

Comment: There are no fundamental changes to how array removal executes between v8 and v9, as the Firestore wire protocol was not changed for the new SDK. Can you set up a minimal reproduction of the difference in performance in a place where we can all test it, such as jsbin or stackblitz?

Comment: Hi @MAZ, any updates?

Comment: @FaridShumbar

Thank you for willing to help with this issue. I want to reproduce this issue, but that requires starting a new project and sharing my credentials here. That may take some time... Also I realized, that array was an initially wrong decision. I will use collections instead

Comment: @FaridShumbar I reconsider my decision and figured out that it was right thing to use array. I found  a workaround way to remove item without using remove function.

Answer (score 1):

After reading article "[Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)"

I found that practice:

> to remove keys, we save the entire array instead of using .remove()

So... I removed item in my code, then updated array and it took less than a second!

```
  // removing item I need to remove at my local array
  const updArr = arr(
    (item) => item !== itemId
  )

  const userRef = doc(db, 'collection', 'id')

  // updating array
  await updateDoc(userRef, {
    gifts: updArr,
  })
```

// p.s.
Obviously, there is some bug at arrayRemove function, but actually we don't have to use that function